# not able to create new instance in asia-south1(mumbai) region

Tags: google-compute-engine

not able to create new instance in GCP asia-south1(mumbai) region. It is working fine for other region but not sure why with mumbai regions. I am facing this issue for almost 5-6 month. have couple of new client but not able to launch instance in mumbai region so have to switch to aws.

Comment: What error message are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are receiving does not pertain to your account specifically, it is a limitation on the Google side where the specific zones in Mumbai are full. Most probably because there are a lot of users in Mumbai that uses GCP. You can check this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003347/gcp-no-resources-available-in-asia-south1-c-since-a-month) to see possible solutions and a more detailed explanation.